# unsupported media type while making ajax web service call

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

the javascript side code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                        var myArray = {"optinh":["header","para1","para2","sendotp","cancel","help","footertext"]};
                        var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(myArray);
                        $.ajax({
            headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: "http://raija04-i140720:8081/vpas/resources/CapDetailService/Strings",
            data: jsonObj,
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
               //  var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                 for (var key in data) {
                    alert(data[key]);
                 }
                $('#header').html(data["header"]);
                $('#para1').html(data["para1"]);
                $('#para2').html(data["para2"]);
                $('#sendotp').html(data["sendotp"]);
                $('#cancel').html(data["cancel"]);
                $('#help').html(data["help"]);
                $('#footertext').html(data["footertext"]);
            },
            error:function(data,status,er) {
                alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
                },

        });
    }
```

and webservice code which is called using ajax call

```
    @POST
    @Path("/Strings")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Object getStrings(/*@QueryParam("user")*/ Util1 jsonObj) { code here

}
```

Object Mapper class for web service

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Util1 {

List<String> optinh = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getOptinh() {
    return optinh;
}

public void setOptinh(List<String> optinh) {
    this.optinh = optinh;
} 

}
```

facing UnSupported media type error

POST http://raija04-i140720:8081/vpas/resources/CapDetailService/Strings 415 (Unsupported Media Type)